# Using Paperclip with Celluloid in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently using Paperclip in Rails 3 to grab a MP4 file, extract a poster frame (jpeg), and to transcode it into three other formats. This works great, but I'm currently running it all on one machine. I'm wondering if anyone here has ever used Celluloid (or any other parallel-ish gems) with Paperclip custom processors?

My custom processors are using avconv to transcode to different resolutions and formats. I think avconv itself can be configured to use multiple threads, but ideally I'd love to be able to scale up by adding worker nodes for transcoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to migrate to a "real" job processing system, where concurrency and distribution are taken care of for you.

Check out [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org), it has all of the features you should need, and as a bonus it is written with Celluloid.